# Is it possible to highlight and underline at the same time?

Tags: highlighting, underline

In looking at [Highlight text with colored underline link to margin notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628759/highlight-text-with-colored-underline-link-to-margin-notes), I was struck by (to me) the unexpectedly attractive look of text that is both highlighted *and* underlined -- certainly not recommended in all cases, but in this it would seem useful. I am somewhat familiar with `soul` and can easily achieve either, but not both. The documentation to `soul` says that nesting is not possible (which I can confirm :<( ). The code for `soul` is daunting and I am disinclined to tinker.

Is this possible?

Comment: well you probably can define your own highlighting style. But it would be easier to use lualatex and lua-ul.

Comment: Hmmm... *lua*latex... hmmm...

Comment: Besides `lua-ul` and `censor`, have a look at `soulpos` (caveat: I’m the author).

Comment: @JavierBezos Have looked and am intrigued!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suitably modified `censor` package may provide something useful, in this regard.  Make sure you get the latest `[2021-12-23]` version loaded, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/censor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}[2021-12-23]
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\censorrule[1]{\textcolor{yellow}{\protect
  \rule[\censorruledepth]{#1}{\censorruleheight}}}

\newcommand\censorul[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\protect
  \rule[\censorruledepth]{#1}{1pt}}}

\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{\bgroup
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \setstackgap{L}{0pt}%
  \stackon{\stackon{\censorrule{\widthofpbox{#1}}}
            {\censorul{\widthofpbox{#1}}}}%
    {#1}%
  \egroup
}

\def\censpace{\rlap{\censorrule{\spacelap}}%
  \rlap{\censorul{\spacelap}} \llap{\censorrule{\spacelap}}%
  \llap{\censorul{\spacelap}}}
\let\sv@censpace\censpace

\censorruledepth -\dp\strutbox
\censorruleheight \baselineskip
\makeatother
\begin{document}
We now have to test this approach.
\xblackout{Testing of a theory is proceeding at this point.
We must see whether line breaking occurs.  I can even include
  expandable macros if I use v 4.0.  See: \expanded{\today}---however, 
  hyphenation will not occur with this approach.}
The test is now complete.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP points out an underlying problem, which extends not only to this solution, but to the `censor` package itself, which I will have to repair.  The problem concerns macros like `\$`, `\#`, `\&`, etc., which should be consor-able, but which do not expand (via `\expanded`) into simple text.

The workaround provided was: `\xblackout{...\censor{\$}...}`.

A better solution is redefine `\xblackout` to look for such characters in the first place and, finding them, censor them without extra user intervention.  The following code block demonstrates how that might be done.  Note, however, a solution such as this will be eventually incorporated into the `censor` package.

Here is the added code needed to redefine `\xblackout` and to incorporate such a character check.  Other character macros can be added to the `\testchars` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\xtokcycleenvironment\xblackoutenv
  {\ifx.##1\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks[1]{\censordot}\else
    \@append\censored@word{##1}%
    \tcpeek\@next\ifx\@next\@tcEscapeptr\@dump\censored@word\fi\fi}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{%
    \testchars{##1}\ifchar\addcytoks{\censor{##1}}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{\censpace}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}

\newif\ifchar
\newcommand\testchars[1]{\charfalse
  \ifx\$#1\chartrue\else
  \ifx\&#1\chartrue\else
  \ifx\##1\chartrue\else
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is excellent and extremely useful! The only problem I can find (by no means a deal breaker) is with `\$` which is not obscured, as in `\xblackout{ABCD\$EFGH}`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sgmoye As a workaround, you can use `\xblackout{ABCD\censor{\$}EFGH}`, but I will try to find a better way.

Comment: @sgmoye Please see the supplement to my answer.